# Detect sign of the shift on Pettitt test

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, change-point

I am doing an analysis of step changes in streamflow time series and I have one question about statistics.

Is it possible to know in the Pettitt test if the shift is upwards or downwards?

Looking at the outputs of the built-in function of R pettitt.test, I am not sure how to know the direction of the shift.

```
> pettitt.test(listDF_Qlowflowma_blending_residuals[[11]]$Q90min)

    Pettitt's test for single change-point detection

data:  listDF_Qlowflowma_blending_residuals[[11]]$Q90min
U* = 893, p-value = 0.03738
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
probable change point at time K 
                             27
```

I know that the statistic took the absolute value, but you could know the direction of the shift by looking at the sign that has the test statistic before applying the absolute value?

Comment: It returns the change point `K` so `is_positive = sign(mean(data[1:K]) < mean(data[(K+1):length(data)]))`